# Problems with installing MIDI library in UECIDE

Tags: uecide

I installed UECIDE from Majenko but I couldn't register nor email him so I try it here.

When trying in install the MIDI library from 47 effects (https://github.com/FortySevenEffects/arduino_midi_library/releases/tag/4.3.1) I get the following error:

```
Compiling Failed
Analyzing Arduino_MIDI_Library_v4.3.1.zip ...
Unable to detect any valid libraries in the archive.
You may need to manually install it or re-package it properly.
```

How to solve this?

I tried install manually by copying files but that didn't result in anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto-install method only (currently) works with old single-arch style libraries. This one is a new multi-arch style library (though it doesn't use the multi-arch facilities).

You need to install it manually.  Simply that means extracting the zip file into "libraries" within your "UECIDE" folder in your documents (My Documents/UECIDE/libraries on Windows, or ~/Documents/UECIDE/libraries on Linux / OS X).

If UECIDE is open at the time you can use "Help -> Debug -> Rebuild internal structures" to re-scan the available libraries, or just close it and re-open it.

Comment: Thanks ... still some errors to be fixed but that's internal in my code. The MIDI library is installed in a breeze.